# Apply animations to A chart engine pie chart

Tags: android, achartengine, pie-chart

I am able to display Pie chart by using A chart engine but I want some animations for that pie chart.

How can I do this?

Comment: Most of animations, (even to use at charts), you can make with standard android animation xml... what kind of animations are you thinking of?

Comment: I want animation like all the slices display one by one and form a pie chart instead of showing pie chart directly or make pie chart to rotate.@Pozzo Apps

Answer (score 2):

For the rotation animation, just call create a `Thread` with a loop inside that would include:

```
renderer.setStartAngle(value);
chartView.repaint();
```

You will increase the value on every iteration in the loop.

Comment: Thankx a lot for your help. Now trying for another charts.

Comment: please could you share the code snippet for the same

Answer (score 0):

For rotation you can do this using Android xml animation framework over the chart view, using .. more about this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

But to show the chart slice by slice it will be harder, you will need to change your Chart Engine.... 2 ways. Make it return every slice in separeted view / drawable and animate it using Android xml... or you can animate direct on canvas. 
But I am not really sure exactly how, it may be kind hard depending on your chat engine.